# Using laravel DB queries but returned as a Eloquent Model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I was wondering if it is possible to query using `DB` facade but returned as an Eloquent Model.

For example i have this query using db query builder

```php
\DB::table('users')->first();
```

But after the query I want all results to be an Eloquent model from `App\User`

same results of this

```php
\App\User::first()
```

my goal for this question is what if I have complex query that returns a sets of users. Using eloquent model is not really efficient i think that's why I use the query builder for raw querying but I also want the results to be a Eloquent model instance.

Comment: @TsaiKoga I don't think it is duplicated. I want to return it as a eloquent model like `App\User` not as a collection

Comment: It will have the same efficiency. The slowness added on Eloquent when you do a query is almost from some data processing when you instantiate the model. If you are going to instantiate it, so you will have the same efficiency.

Comment: @Don'tPanic thank you for pointing out. let me check it.

Comment: @EliasSoares I thought of that also but maybe there are some small differences i'll have to check it my self

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can use the `collect` function, It can help you to have many methods like what eloquent return to you. You can see all the methods [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods).

The code would look like :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

collect(DB::table('users')->first())
```

Comment: unfortunately collect function is not what I am looking for. collect function convert an array into collection. What I want is to return the query into a eloquent model

Comment: `collect()` makes a collection, it does not magically convert an array to a Model instance.

Comment: Yeah, I said it just like, but of course it's not a model instance

Comment: DB already returns a collection